# errors get deleted when set inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a before_create callback that sets an error inside an object.

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord:base
   #omitted code
   def check_animal_has_non_poisoned_food
      if self.food.non_poisoned_food.nil?
        self.errors[:non_poisoned_food] = "Animal has non poisoned food"
        return false
      end
   end
end
```

for some reason, inside the controller, when I do an update attribute, although it fails validation

```
if animal.update_attributes(params[:animal])
  #ommitted
else
  #goes here
  ap animal.errors //empty
end
```

there is no error inside the `animal.errors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in there that you're adding an error. Typically that looks like this:

```
self.errors.add("Animal has non poisoned food")
```

Adding it to the attributes isn't going to render it as an error even if you `return false` to break the create chain.

Comment: @denniss..have you made `check_animal_has_non_poisoned_food` method as a `before_create` callback? Then it wont be called during updation of a record(it will be called only during creation). You should be using `before_save` callback, if u want it for both creation and updation.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do `validates :non_poisoned_food, :presence => true, :message => "..."` instead of your own version?

Comment: @tadman: it's really hard to explain but the idea is for food to check  the owner (animal) for other foods that animal has and checks to make sure that there is a non_poisoned food among all those. problem is that there is a validation at the animal level but when the food gets deleted or modified, the animal's validation will not get run again. =__= sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: Why not just re-save the animal model when you change the food as a matter of course, then you'll get your errors if they happen using `animal.save!`